# Loop doesn't process other files in the directory

Tags: python

```
me=1

while (me < 244):
    f=open('%s' % me, 'rb')

    tdata = f.read()
    f.close()

    ss = '\xff\xd8'
    se = '\xff\xd9'

    count = 0
    start = 0
    while True:
        x1 = tdata.find(ss,start)
        if x1 < 0:
            break
        x2 = tdata.find(se,x1)
        jpg = tdata[x1:x2+1]
        count += 1
        fname = 'extracted%d03.jpg' % (count)
        fw = open(fname,'wb')
        fw.write(jpg)
        fw.close()
        start = x2+2
        me=me+1
```

I am trying to run this for multiple files.
But it only does the operation for file 1 and rest of the files are ignored.
I am very new with python can anyone tweak this a bit?

Comment: @PaulRooney I have used '%s' % me, 'rb' to use the 1 as file name
And the filename is not with any extension 
The code is to extract jpg from thumbnail data

Comment: I ran this with some dummy files, and the program went through them quite nicely.  Please post code and data that reproduce the problem.

Comment: You have `me=me+1` inside the `while True` loop. If your first file has more that 243 instances of what you are `find`ing, the outer loop will only run once. In short, move the incrementation of `me` outside the inner loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your last line of code you're incrementing `me` inside of your nested while loop that you want to run for each of your files. To fix it, just un-indent `me` like so.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

me=1

while (me < 244):
    f=open('%s' % me, 'rb')

    tdata = f.read()
    f.close()

    ss = '\xff\xd8'
    se = '\xff\xd9'

    count = 0
    start = 0
    while True:
        x1 = tdata.find(ss,start)
        if x1 < 0:
            break
        x2 = tdata.find(se,x1)
        jpg = tdata[x1:x2+1]
        count += 1
        fname = 'extracted%d03.jpg' % (count)
        fw = open(fname,'wb')
        fw.write(jpg)
        fw.close()
        start = x2+2

    me=me+1  # this needs to be outside of your nested while loop
```

That being said, you probably want to improve the names of the variables in this code (make them more descriptive!), and it would probably also be a good idea to extract the code in the while loop into a function. It's also worth mentioning that the outer while loop can be (and should be) replaced with a for loop.

Something like this:

```
def do_something_with_file(me):
    f=open('%s' % me, 'rb')

    tdata = f.read()
    f.close()

    ss = '\xff\xd8'
    se = '\xff\xd9'

    count = 0
    start = 0
    while True:
        x1 = tdata.find(ss,start)
        if x1 < 0:
            break
        x2 = tdata.find(se,x1)
        jpg = tdata[x1:x2+1]
        count += 1
        fname = 'extracted%d03.jpg' % (count)
        fw = open(fname,'wb')
        fw.write(jpg)
        fw.close()
        start = x2+2


for i in range(1, 244):
    do_something_with_file(i)
```